# Creating enemies that slide along a patrol path

Tags: 2d, movement, godot-3

I have created a 2D game in Godot 3.5.2. I have enemy scene which has node as Area2D and child as AnimatedSprite and Collision. I want to create enemy movement like in [Pixel Adventure](https://pixelfrog-assets.itch.io/pixel-adventure-1):

[image]

But I am not able to do so. Please help me.

Comment: you're asking for some actual basic godot stuff. I would recommend to watch through some youtube tutorial and official documentation because you'll find exactly what you're asking for

Comment: There's multiple types of Collision nodes in Godot 3.5 - which one specifically are you trying to use?

Comment: How did you try creating this movement so far, and what obstacle did you encounter that made you "not able to do so"? The better you can describe what aspect you need help with, the better users here can target their answers to help you.